# MS Access Query ColumnHidden Property

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've written some VBA code that (a) sets the SQL of a query based on input variables, (b) opens the query in datasheet view, and (c) hides or shows columns based on "true" / "false" values of check boxes in another table. This is considering the "ColumnHidden" property as described in Microsoft Dev Center help. [Dev Center Help - ColumnHidden Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224064(v=office.11).aspx)

When executing the code, (a) and (b) are working as intended. However, I get error 3270, "Property not found" at line `fld.Properties("ColumnHidden") = False` when executing (c). I've been unable to resolve the issue, even when trying the error handling method described in the Dev Center. Please help!

```
Dim rsLabel As DAO.Recordset, rsCOlumn As DAO.Recordset
Dim qryCPQ As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strLabel As String, strSQL As String, strColumn As String
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim prp As DAO.Property
Dim AttArray As Variant
Dim x As Integer


ReDim AttArray(19, 1)
For x = 1 To 20
    AttArray(x - 1, 1) = "Att" & x
Next x

strLabel = "SELECT * FROM PM_qryLabels2 WHERE CAT_ID=" & Forms!CM_frmCollectionReportPre!cboFamily
Set rsLabel = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strLabel, dbOpenSnapshot)
rsLabel.MoveFirst

For x = 1 To 20
    If Not IsNull(rsLabel.Fields("Att" & x)) Then
        AttArray(x - 1, 1) = rsLabel.Fields("Att" & x)
    Else
        AttArray(x - 1, 1) = "Att" & x
    End If
Next x


With CurrentDb
    Set qryCPQ = .QueryDefs("CM_qryCollectionReport")

    strSQL = "SELECT CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CATEGORY, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.Part_No, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_Material, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborMach, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborAssy, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborPipe, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborTest, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborPack, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborShip, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_Sub, " & _
             "PM_qryOptions.Att1 As [" & AttArray(0, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att2 As [" & AttArray(1, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att3 As [" & AttArray(2, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att4 As [" & AttArray(3, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att5 As [" & AttArray(4, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att6 As [" & AttArray(5, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att7 As [" & AttArray(6, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att8 As [" & AttArray(7, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att9 As [" & AttArray(8, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att10 As [" & AttArray(9, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att11 As [" & AttArray(10, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att12 As [" & AttArray(11, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att13 As [" & AttArray(12, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att14 As [" & AttArray(13, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att15 As [" & AttArray(14, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att16 As [" & AttArray(15, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att17 As [" & AttArray(16, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att18 As [" & AttArray(17, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att19 As [" & AttArray(18, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att20 As [" & AttArray(19, 1) & "] " & _
             "FROM CM_qryCollectionEdit2 INNER JOIN PM_qryOptions ON CM_qryCollectionEdit2.Part_No = PM_qryOptions.Part_No " & _
             "WHERE ((CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CAT_ID)=" & Me.cboFamily & " AND ((CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_Publish)=True));"
    qryCPQ.SQL = strSQL
    qryCPQ.Close
    Set qryCPQ = Nothing
End With

DoCmd.OpenQuery "CM_qryCollectionReport", , acReadOnly

Set dbs = CurrentDb

For x = 1 To 20
    Set fld = dbs.QueryDefs!CM_qryCollectionReport.Fields(AttArray(x - 1, 1))
    fld.Properties("ColumnHidden") = False

    strColumn = "SELECT * FROM PM_Attributes WHERE CAT_ID=" & Forms!CM_frmCollectionReportPre!cboFamily & " AND [ATTRIBUTE]='" & AttArray(x - 1, 1) & "'"
    Set rsCOlumn = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strColumn, dbOpenSnapshot)

    If Not rsCOlumn.EOF Then
        If rsCOlumn![CPQ_Publish] = False Then
            fld.Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
        End If
    End If

    rsCOlumn.Close
    Set rsCOlumn = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
Next x


Set dbs = Nothing

DoCmd.Close acForm, "CM_frmCollectionReportPre", acSaveNo
```

Per Eric Von Asmuth's suggestion, I've added in the error handling, so the code now appears as follows. Yet I still receive error 3270 at the same location. Hasn't fixed a thing.

```
Dim rsLabel As DAO.Recordset, rsCOlumn As DAO.Recordset
Dim qryCPQ As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strLabel As String, strSQL As String, strColumn As String
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim prp As DAO.Property
Dim AttArray As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Const conErrPropertyNotFound = 3270

' Turn off error trapping
On Error Resume Next

ReDim AttArray(19, 1)
For x = 1 To 20
    AttArray(x - 1, 1) = "Att" & x
Next x

strLabel = "SELECT * FROM PM_qryLabels2 WHERE CAT_ID=" & Forms!CM_frmCollectionReportPre!cboFamily
Set rsLabel = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strLabel, dbOpenSnapshot)
rsLabel.MoveFirst

For x = 1 To 20
    If Not IsNull(rsLabel.Fields("Att" & x)) Then
        AttArray(x - 1, 1) = rsLabel.Fields("Att" & x)
    Else
        AttArray(x - 1, 1) = "Att" & x
    End If
Next x

'AFTER FORM IS OPEN, NEED TO HIDE COLUMNS BASEDON CPQ_PUBLISH

With CurrentDb
    Set qryCPQ = .QueryDefs("CM_qryCollectionReport")

    strSQL = "SELECT CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CATEGORY, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.Part_No, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_Material, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborMach, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborAssy, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborPipe, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborTest, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborPack, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_LaborShip, CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_Sub, " & _
                        "PM_qryOptions.Att1 As [" & AttArray(0, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att2 As [" & AttArray(1, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att3 As [" & AttArray(2, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att4 As [" & AttArray(3, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att5 As [" & AttArray(4, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att6 As [" & AttArray(5, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att7 As [" & AttArray(6, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att8 As [" & AttArray(7, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att9 As [" & AttArray(8, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att10 As [" & AttArray(9, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att11 As [" & AttArray(10, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att12 As [" & AttArray(11, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att13 As [" & AttArray(12, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att14 As [" & AttArray(13, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att15 As [" & AttArray(14, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att16 As [" & AttArray(15, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att17 As [" & AttArray(16, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att18 As [" & AttArray(17, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att19 As [" & AttArray(18, 1) & "], PM_qryOptions.Att20 As [" & AttArray(19, 1) & "] " & _
                "FROM CM_qryCollectionEdit2 INNER JOIN PM_qryOptions ON CM_qryCollectionEdit2.Part_No = PM_qryOptions.Part_No " & _
                "WHERE ((CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CAT_ID)=" & Me.cboFamily & " AND ((CM_qryCollectionEdit2.CPQ_Publish)=True));"
    qryCPQ.SQL = strSQL
    qryCPQ.Close
    'Set qryCPQ = Nothing
End With

DoCmd.OpenQuery "CM_qryCollectionReport", , acReadOnly

Set dbs = CurrentDb

For x = 1 To 20
    Set fld = dbs.QueryDefs!CM_qryCollectionReport.Fields(AttArray(x - 1, 1))
    fld.Properties("ColumnHidden") = False

    ' Error may have occurred when value was set.
    ' Display error message or create property when property didn't exist
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If Err.Number <> conErrPropertyNotFound Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            MsgBox "Couldn't set property 'ColumnHidden' " & _
                   "on field '" & fld.Name & "'", vbCritical
        Else
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("ColumnHidden", dbLong, False)
            fld.Properties.Append prp
        End If
    End If


    strColumn = "SELECT * FROM PM_Attributes WHERE CAT_ID=" & Forms!CM_frmCollectionReportPre!cboFamily & " AND [ATTRIBUTE]='" & AttArray(x - 1, 1) & "'"
    Set rsCOlumn = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strColumn, dbOpenSnapshot)

    If Not rsCOlumn.EOF Then
        If rsCOlumn![CPQ_Publish] = False Then
            fld.Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
        End If
    End If

    rsCOlumn.Close
    Set rsCOlumn = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set prp = Nothing
Next x

Set dbs = Nothing

DoCmd.Close acForm, "CM_frmCollectionReportPre", acSaveNo
```

Screen shots of error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you closely look at the example code in the article you referred to, it includes error capturing, and creating the property if it didn't exist. This is because the property may or may not exist based on unpredictable circumstances.

*Adapted from the [Linked article:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224064(v=office.11).aspx)*

```
 Const conErrPropertyNotFound = 3270

' Turn off error trapping.
On Error Resume Next

'Set the field to false here
fld.Properties("ColumnHidden") = False

' Error may have occurred when value was set.
' Display error message or create property when property didn't exist
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    If Err.Number <> conErrPropertyNotFound Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "Couldn't set property 'ColumnHidden' " & _
               "on field '" & fld.Name & "'", vbCritical
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("ColumnHidden", dbLong, False)
        fld.Properties.Append prp
    End If
End If
```

Since you've already set the field to `False`, you don't need to error trap in case the field doesn't exist when setting it back to `True`

You can also choose to check if the property does exist by iterating through all properties, which is best done in a separate function. This avoids error trapping, but may take longer to run

Comment: I mentioned up above that I already tried the error handling method described, and it did not fix the problem. I pasted it in just like you've shown above, yet the same error still exists. I still need a solution.

Comment: @jhalf2008 You can't get an error you're explicitly handling, so please, be more descriptive

Comment: My understanding is that "On Error Resume Next" is supposed to execute the next line of code, continuing execution once the error is encountered. That's not happening. I still get error 3270 pop up on my screen and the code pauses. My second understanding is that when property doesn't exist, the error handling script you've provided above is intended to create the property. That's also not happening as the error 3270 is still occurring. It's like I never pasted in the error handling at all. I'd paste in my edited code here to show you but am unable to do so in a Comment.

Comment: Then edit your question. I would appreciate a small screenshot of the error popup too (because I truly can't imagine a normal error popup after `On Error Resume Next`)

Comment: Edited to add screen shots. Maybe "On Error Resume Next" is in the wrong spot? I have it at the top of the code. Didn't know if location matters. I'm not understanding how skipping over the error fixes my problem. Isn't it just a band aid to keep the code running?

Comment: Your code is indeed in the wrong place. You're calling `On Error GoTo 0` in the loop, and `On Error Resume Next` outside of the loop. This means that only for the first iteration of the loop errors are handled correctly. Please move `On Error Resume Next` directly in front of the line causing the error.

Comment: I've moved "On Error Resume Next" as prescribed. It has corrected the error from popping up. However, columns are not being hidden which leads me to suspect that the error handling is simply skipping over the error, and not setting the property to fix the problem. Hiding of certain columns is supposed to occur at the line that checks rsCOlumn![CPQ_Publish] = False and then changes the "ColumnHidden" property to "True". But it must not be working because it isn't hiding the column. Any thoughts here?

Comment: That's a a separate issue, you're turning the default error handling back on as soon as you hit `On Error GoTo 0`, so it's on when you hit `fld.Properties("ColumnHidden") = True`. That means the property has been added succesfully, but somehow isn't influencing what you see. That's likely because you've already opened the query. Try opening the query after instead of before hiding the columns.

Comment: I moved the DoCmd.OpenQuery statement to the end of the code, after the for loop. Upon the query opening, the result did not change. Columns are still not being hidden when their CPQ_Publish value is false.